# Kivy mainloop not closing even after on_release function is completed

Tags: python, kivy

'Submit' button in my app , opens a windows dialog box to take an input file location of the selected file and passes it to self.path inside press() function. If the correct input file is passed then, the app's backend algorithm runs and completes after certain steps. If windows dialog box is closed, then '' is passed as the file path. press() does the relevant steps shown in the code, when '' is passed.

In both these cases, even though the press() function is completed , the app still stays in the mainloop. As in, I have to click anywhere in the app to 'stop' this running and then click the 'submit' button again to take the input file location for the next iteration. So basically, if i click the submit button immediately after the press() is completed, then nothing would happen. I will have to click the 'submit' button again to open the windows dialog box. I have best described this issue based on my beginner level knowledge in kivy (starting to learn basically). I am not sure if this is an issue with kivy or my code. I have attached app's python code and builder code for reference.

App's main code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
import first
import back_end
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)

# from kivy.core.window import Window
# Window.clearcolor = (169/255, 219/255, 206/255, 1)
Builder.load_file('UI_First.kv')

class EnterScreen(Widget):

    def press(self):

        file_upload = tk.Tk()
        file_upload.withdraw()
        self.path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        self.simulation()

    def simulation(self):
        file_format = ''

        if self.path != '':
            dot_index = self.path.index('.')
            file_format = self.path[dot_index]
            for p in range(dot_index+1, len(self.path)):
                file_format += self.path[p]

        if self.path != '' and file_format == '.xlsx':
            val = back_end.back_end_algo(self.path)
        elif self.path != '' and file_format != '.xlsx':
            print('upload correct data file')
        elif self.path == '':
            pass



class Awesome(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root_screen =EnterScreen()
        return self.root_screen

if __name__=='__main__':
    Awesome().run()
```

Builder code - UI_First.kv :

```
    #: import utils kivy.utils
<Label>
    font_size: 20


<EnterScreen>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 70
        spacing: 40

        Label:
            text: 'Select data to be simulated'
            color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#0a0000')
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.95}
            background_color: (74/255,181/255,151/255,0.6)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: self.background_color
                RoundedRectangle:
                    size: 300,100
                    pos: 125,455


        Button:
            text: 'Submit'
            #font_size: 32            
            on_release: root.press()
            #background_normal: ''
            #background_down: ''
            #background_color: (169/255, 219/255, 206/255, 1)
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.95}
            size_hint:(None,None)
            width: 200
            height: 50
```

Comment: It may be that you are running `back_end.back_end_algo(self.path)` on the main thread. That will prevent any interaction with the GUI from working correctly. Perhaps you should run that code on another thread.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i am new to Object oriented programming in Python. May i know what do you mean by thread? How do i change this code to implement your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running `back_end_algo()` on the main thread. Since the GUI event loop runs on the main thread, your GUI will not function while your `back_end_algo()` is running. Try running your `back_end_algo()` in another thread. perhaps like this:

```
def simulation(self):
    file_format = ''

    if self.path != '':
        dot_index = self.path.index('.')
        file_format = self.path[dot_index]
        for p in range(dot_index+1, len(self.path)):
            file_format += self.path[p]

    if self.path != '' and file_format == '.xlsx':
        threading.Thread(target=self.run_backend_algo).start()
    elif self.path != '' and file_format != '.xlsx':
        print('upload correct data file')
    elif self.path == '':
        pass

def run_backend_algo(self):
    val = back_end.back_end_algo(self.path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the help. The issue is almost solved, now i am able to click the UI without it going to 'Not responding' while the backend is running. But still the UI is sorta unresponsive or static while the backend is running or even after it finishes running. I have to click somewhere in the UI window to 'restart' it again in laymans's terms. To explain what i mean, During this state , the app's name is un-highlighted at the top of the UI window. It is almost like when we use MS office tools and switch over to some other app and come back to MS office again , we will have to click somewhere in the MS office UI to go into its editing mode. The same thing is happening. I have attached the screenshot of this state of the app in this comment.[Screenshot before clicking in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubzmc.png)

Once i click somewhere in the UI , it becomes like what is shown in the next screenshot. After this 'clicking only' , the 'Submit' button starts to work again.

[Screenshot after clicking in UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdwBa.png)

Comment: I have figured this out. I had to destroy the Tkinter file_upload variable after i get self.path. Kivy was still running because file_upload had not been destroyed